# Watermark error in \documentclass[]{exam}

Tags: exam

I'm adding a water mark to my assessments (`\documentclass[11pt,answers,addpoints]{exam}`), and I'm using the following commands,

```
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\newwatermark*[allpages,%
 color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]%
{Confidential}
```

but I'm getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Would be easier if you could provide a Minimal Working Example (aka MWE), begining with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: I recently learned the package [CTAN eso-pic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) has better results than `xwatermark`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `xwatermark` is known to cooperate poorly with other packages. Try instead :

```
\documentclass[11pt,answers,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents=Confidential,color=red}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

which seems to give what you expected.

Comment: Thank you, it worked